# platform-specific std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num

Tags: c++, time, std

I've noticed that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num = 1` for every system I've tested. Does there exist any system (embedded, desktop, mobile, or otherwise) where it happens to be some other number? (On such a system, 1 second would not be representable in ticks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three implementations of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` that I am aware of:  Visual Studio, gcc and clang (when used with libc++).

All three of these have nanosecond-precision (`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num = 1`).  For VS and libc++, `high_resolution_clock` is type-aliased to `steady_clock`.  On gcc it is type-aliased to `system_clock`.

There is nothing in the spec that prevents `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num != 1`, and you are correct that on such a system 1 second would not be representable in "ticks".  This further translates to:

> `seconds` would not be implicitly convertible to `high_resolution_clock::duration`.

To find the coarsest duration to which both `seconds` and `high_resolution_clock::duration` are convertible to, you can portably use:

```
using CT = common_type_t<seconds, high_resolution_clock::duration>;
```

For all of the implementations I'm aware of, `CT` is a type-alias for `nanoseconds`.