# How accurate is std::chrono?

Tags: c++, time, precision, c++-chrono

`std::chrono` advertises that it can report results down to the nanosecond level. On a typical x86_64 Linux or Windows machine, how accurate would one expect this to be? What would be the error bars for a measurement of 10 ns, 10 µs, 10 ms, and 10 s, for example?

Comment: What clock from `chrono` are you asking about?

Comment: But let's say `high_resolution_clock` for this purpose

Comment: I forget, but doesn't a given clock tell you about its resolution?

Comment: It probably depends on your hardware and OS. What the library can support and what the platform provides are two different things.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687645)

Comment: @DrewDormann I don't believe so. That question is asking about a different concept than the underlying precision of the clock itself.

Comment: I tried doing `std::cout << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period().num << '/' << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period().den << std::endl;` but you get 1e-9 which can't possibly be right, right? Can my laptop measure nanoseconds?

Comment: for future readers: please note the important difference between the resolution (`period()`) and accuracy. For instance (a purly hypothetical example, not necessary tied to C++) a clock with nanoseconds resolution could have 0.5 nanoseconds accuracy or 3 nanoseconds resolution or 500 nanoseconds accuracy. The question is about accuracy.

Comment: Querying `period` is wrong. `period` gives you the *resolution* of the clock, but it doesn't give you the *accuracy* of the clock. Very different concepts. `steady_clock` is required to yield nanosecond-resolution, but there's no requirement that it tick upwards by increments of exactly 1 nanosecond per nanosecond; usually, it ticks upwards by significantly larger intervals.

Comment: Call `now()` twice in a row with optimization on, and print out the difference.  Try it in a loop too.  Results vary with platform and current load.

Comment: @Carbon a modest 2 GHz processor has a clock period of `0.5 nanoseconds` and while this doesn't necessary means a 0.5 nanoseconds accuracy, it most certainly means *your laptop* can measure nanoseconds

Comment: @bolov You are also [conflating precision with accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter#Use). It's a surprisingly hard problem. It's usually best to use the most accurate OS API, and if that isn't sufficient, give up…

Comment: @ArneVogel very possible I am confusing concepts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's most likely hardware and OS dependent. For example when I ask Windows what the clock frequency is using QueryPerformanceFrequency() I get 3903987, which if you take the inverse of that you get a clock period or resolution of about 256 nanoseconds. This is the value that that my operating system reports.

With std::chrono according to the docs the minimum representable duration is high_resolution_clock::period::num / high_resolution_clock::period::den.

The num and den are numerator and denominator. std::chrono::high_resolution_clock tells me the numerator is 1, and the denominator is 1 billion, supposedly corresponding to 1 nanosecond:

```
std::cout << (double)std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num /   
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den; // Results in a nanosecond.
```

So according to the std::chrono I have one nanosecond resolution but I don't believe it because the native OS system call is more likely to be reporting the more accurate frequency/period.

Comment: Right, so how accurate is it? If I do  `auto st = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 auto en = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(en - st).count() << std::endl;` I get about 890 ns - based on this that, I should expect it to be about +/- 250 ns?

Comment: @Carbon I asked a similar question and I still don't know the answer. The consensus seemed to be to trust the native OS function, which I'm pretty sure the C++ standard library has to rely on anyway.

Comment: @Carbon There's always going to be additional inaccuracies caused by the fact that `clock::now` has overhead of its own, *and* because your system is not a *Real Time* system, and thus there's fewer guarantees about how quickly the CPU will resolve your queries. Example: your current process might get preempted by another process for a few microseconds in between the calls to `clock::now()`.

Comment: Actually resolution and accuracy are two different things. If a computer hw clock drifts away from the correct time  and then it is resynced via NTP, the computer time *has* to be very inaccurate during the resync process.

I understand the c++ standard does not  give any guarantees or hint how a std::chrono implementation shroud deal with this, except  that time never runs backward.

Answer (score 5):

The accuracy  of a chrono clock depends on the implementation and AFAIK there is no standard API to query it. On POSIX clocks are normally implemented using [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/clock_gettime.html) and the resolution can be as high as 1ns as reported by `clock_getres`.

However, you probably want to take into account the overhead of calling the `now()` function (including the overhead of the underlying API) which can be much higher than the reported resolution. It can be measured as follows ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/bzfaMfbjh)):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int num_measurements = 100;
  using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  clock::time_point measurements[num_measurements];
  for (int i = 0; i < num_measurements; ++i) {
    measurements[i] = clock::now();
  }
  auto min_duration = clock::duration::max();
  for (int i = 1; i < num_measurements; ++i) {
    auto duration = measurements[i] - measurements[i - 1];
    if (duration != clock::duration() && duration < min_duration)
      min_duration = duration;
  }
  std::cout << min_duration;
}
```

Some measurement results (may vary per system):

- On libstdc++ and Linux used by godbolt this gives ~20ns.
- On libc++ and macOS this gives ~41ns.

Note that the initial call to `now` or `clock_gettime` is almost always slower than the subsequent calls, possibly due to caching or branch prediction.

Comment: I noticed that the results vary significantly if you have CPU scaling enabled. On linux use `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` to disable it and get consistent results. If I do this, I get 16ns on my old i7-2600 on linux amd64.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy will depend upon the application and how this application interacts with the operating system. I am not familiar with chrono specifically, but there are limitations at a lower level you must account for.

For example, if you timestamp network packets using the CPU, the measurement accuracy is very noisy. Even though the precision of the time measurement may be 1 nanosecond, the context switch time for the interrupt corresponding to the packet arrival may be ~1 microsecond. You can accurately measure when your application processes the packet, but not what time the packet arrived.

Answer (score -2):

### Short answer: Not accurate in microseconds and below.

Long answer:

I was interested to know about how much my two dp program takes time to execute. So I used the [chrono](https://cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) library, but when I ran it it says 0 microseconds. So technically I was unable to compare. I can't increase the array size, because it will not be possible to extend it to 1e8.

So I wrote a sort program to test it and ran it for 100 and the following is the result:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjB6r.png)

It is clearly visible that it is not consistent for same input, so I would recommend not to use for higher precision.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: What is a "dp program"?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69080088/edit) (it covers answers and program output as well). Thanks in advance.